# Trying to update the meta description of the home page

Tags: description

We use the Yoast SEO extension and under Search Appearance, in the meta description box, I have updated our Wordpress blog's meta description an saved the changes.

[image: see screenshot]

It has however been more than a month now and the description has not changed when I Google for our name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The meta description is a *suggestion*. Google can decide to display something else in the result if it wants. Especially if it’s more relevant to the user’s search. Google is not a phone book, they don’t just list what you ask them to.

Comment: we have little to 0 control over google search results in displaying modified content. URLs. etc...just pray to God a miracle will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your site's meta description tag? May be, there are more than one meta description tag. That's why, you are not seeing your preferred description in Google.

If it is not the case, then Google might have ignored your preferred meta description. To solve this issue, you have to use a different one.